# Encrypting data from a file into a temporary file stored in /tmp/ using tr command

Tags: linux

I'm trying to encrypt data from a file into a temporary file stored in /temp/ using the tr command. This is what I have so far:

```
echo " file to be encrypted : "
    read file
    $ cat file | tr "a-wxyz" "d-zabc" > /tmp/file
```

But apparently it is not doing what I want.

Comment: `But appearntly it not doing what i want!` -- It might help to understand what is it doing, and what is it that you want it to do.

Comment: I hope this "encryption" is only for learning purpose? If it's in a production code, don't do that! Such "encryption" provides exactly 0 security. Better take a look into serious encryption: OpenSSL (http://www.openssl.org) and OpenPGP (http://www.openpgp.org) are both good and not too hard tools to use.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot some tiny, but essential symbol before variable: `$`.
This should work:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo " file to be encrypted : "
    read file
    cat $file | tr "a-wxyz" "d-zabc" > /tmp/file
```

However, keep in mind, that such "encryption" does not provide *any* security, so if you really need encryption, consider using tools made specially for this purpose. [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) and [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/) are both great tools.